# Simple I am sure: Printing 2 columns with header and results -- new to python

Tags: python-3.x, printing, vertical-alignment, chr

I am new to python and did not see this exact questions or answers that will work.  I am using Python 3.7 and simply need to display the character codes for uppercase alphabet letters (A-Z).  I have that part, but it also requires the output be printed so each letter and character code appear on a separate line divided into two columns with a label.

My code works great but prints horizontally (which I prefer, but the instructions are to print vertically with a header).

```
def uppercaseAlphabets():
    # uppercase
    for c in range(65, 91):
        print(chr(c), end=" ");

    print("");


# Function to print the alphabet upper case codes
def uppercaseCodes():
    for c in range(65, 91):
        print((c), end=" ");
    print("");


print("Uppercase Alphabets");
uppercaseAlphabets();

print("Uppercase Codes ");
uppercaseCodes();
```

The result is:

```
Uppercase Alphabet
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z 
Uppercase Codes 
65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90
```

I want it to look like this:

```
Uppercase Alphabet     Uppercase Codes
         A                    65
         B                    66
         C                    67
```

and so on.  Any tweeks to my code are appreaciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use formatted print output:

```
print(f"{'Uppercase Alphabet':^20}{'Uppercase Codes':^20}")

# try to avoid magic numbers, in 20 days it will be unclear why range(65, 91) is used
# you can get the code from the letter to make it clearer to understand after years
# you need ord("Z")+1 as range does not provide the upper limit
for code in range(ord("A"), ord("Z")+1):
    print(f"{chr(code):^20}{code:^20}")
```

Output:

```
Uppercase Alphabet   Uppercase Codes
         A                   65         
         B                   66         
         C                   67         
         D                   68         
         E                   69         
         F                   70         
         G                   71         
         H                   72         
         I                   73         
         J                   74         
         K                   75         
         L                   76         
         M                   77         
         N                   78         
         O                   79         
         P                   80         
         Q                   81         
         R                   82         
         S                   83         
         T                   84         
         U                   85         
         V                   86         
         W                   87         
         X                   88         
         Y                   89         
         Z                   90
```

Documentation:

- [formatted string literals ("f-strings")](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)
  and  [format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)
- [format mini language (`:^20` == center in 20 spaces )](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

Comment: Thank you.  That was fast and I appreciate your help.  Im still getting used to Python.